# Почему RubyMine не видит Rails 3.2.11 ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Проблема в вот в чем. Уставновил Rails версии 3.2.11.
Установил Rubymine 5.0 
Когда пытаюсь создать с нуля проект. В окне настройки приложения Rails 
не выводится в пункте выбора мой свежо установленный Rails 3.2.11. Но, тогда я пытаюсь установить Rails через Rubymine, где она сама мне предлагает установить.
Нажимаю установить. И вылезает ошибка.
Устанавливал по этой схеме: http://rails.hasbrains.ru/questions/123
Тех. данные: ubuntu 12.10, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.11, nodejs 0.6.19,

> Following gems were not installed:
> rails (3.2.11):  Error installing rails:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.          /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)   from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'     from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'   Gem files will remain installed in /home/ruzel/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection. Results logged to /home/ruzel/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Answer (score 1):

RM > Preferences > Ruby SDK and Gems > Ruby interpreter (выбрать если не стоит версию руби)

ps: Используйте RVM или rbenv.

Comment: я Rails устанавливал через RVM

Comment: Руби вы имеете в виду? Рельсы вы ставили через гемсы (:
Починился рубимайн? Всё ок?